# SQL Server : SELECT from a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling with this: I have two SQL statements that have 2 different sets of keywords. These are stored in temporary tables since I cannot update, delete or insert into a table.

How do I write a third SQL statement (limited on SQL characters in each statement) that says: "If 'pingu' and 'noot' is correct then true, otherwise if 'sponge' and 'bob' are true display results" (this works)? But then how do I say: "if 'pingu' and 'sponge' is selected then true, or 'bob' and 'noot' are selected then true", but keeping the 'pingu' and 'noot' as true if selected?

Example of keyword list 1: '**Pingu**' and '**Noot**'

```
DECLARE @teststring varchar(512) = '{KEYWORD}' 
SELECT TOP 1 k.type 
FROM (VALUES

('pingu', '66'), ('noot', '66'))

k(word,type) WHERE @teststring LIKE '%' + k.word + '%' 

GROUP BY k.type 
HAVING COUNT(1) >=2
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

Example of keyword list 2: '**Sponge**' and '**Bob**'

```
DECLARE @teststring varchar(512) = '{KEYWORD}' 

SELECT TOP 1 k.type 
FROM (VALUES ('sponge', '66'), ('bob', '66')) k (word, type) 
WHERE @teststring LIKE '%' + k.word + '%' 
GROUP BY k.type 
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... You have a table with all 4 records, or?  What mean of "selected", in the keyword?  Try to create a table with all sample records, instead of sample record per test case.

Comment: Hello, well we have two sql strings which have 2 keywords in each, we have to use temporary tables due to limitations of the software.

Comment: I've read this a couple times and I still don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you provide an example of what you expect to get out of the 3rd statement?

Answer (score 0):

What about combining the two source queries with a `UNION ALL`?

For example (adapting your original queries):

```
DECLARE @teststring varchar(512) = '{KEYWORD}';

WITH Keywords AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('pingu', '66'), ('noot', '66')) k(word, type)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES ('sponge', '66'), ('bob', '66')) k(word, type) 
)

SELECT TOP 1 k.type 
FROM Keywords k
WHERE @teststring LIKE '%' + k.word + '%' 
GROUP BY k.type 
HAVING COUNT(1) >=2
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

This returns a result row if at least two keywords, *regardless* of which source query the keywords come from, are found in `@teststring`.

*Note: If your keywords lists are large, it may be worth reworking the query so that an index can be used to make processing the `WHERE` clause more efficient.*